# Is it OK to push my code to GitHub while it is still in early development?

Tags: open-source, github, project-hosting

I have some projects that are in a very early development state. They are nowhere nearing completion but I do host them (as public repos) on GitHub because:

- I have multiple computers and I want access to my code everywhere
- I want a backup for my code
- I want it to be easy if someone wants to collaborate in some way
- I use GitHub Issues as a poor man's project management software

Is it OK to publish a project on GitHub even when it is very early in the development? I am a bit concerned about someone to come by and say `OMG this is total BS, this code is so bad!` while looking at unpolished/still in development/not tested code.

What are your practices when you start new public projects? Do you wait until you have something substantial to show or you create a bare repo directly on GitHub and start from there?

I used `GitHub` throughout this post but this applies to every code hosting service out there.

Comment: Does GitHub give you the option to restric access?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Only for paid accounts. Though nobody can push directly to your repo. For this they have to create a pull request and I have to approve it and merge it myself.

Comment: Ah. Paid accounts are pretty pricey?

Comment: Could use Bitbucket (Free) and keep it private repo then make it public once you feel it is ok to be seen.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Not that much. From 7$/month. But I'm pretty sure you knew that already, didn't you? :P You only wanted me to realise that I could just pay for it and shut up. Just kidding by the way :P

Comment: @marco-fiset: Actually, no, I *didn't* know it was that cheap. Never looked into it. If it's that cheap though... Hmmm. I might have to set up an account of my own. Thanks for bringing that to my attention! ;)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Of course it is OK: it is hard to imagine that over 4,098,118 projects currently hosted on GitHub would all be 100% great and useful! You are not forcing anyone to use your code or even to look at it. If you host the project primarily for yourself, the quality of your code is of concern to you, and nobody else.

You listed all the right reasons to host your project - backups, universal access, and possibility of collaboration with others are great reasons to start hosting as early as possible.

Answer (score 12):

Push whatever you want as early as possible.  No one's going to look at it unless you publicise it and it's interesting.

If you're really worried, some free code hosting services offer private repositories.

Comment: One such service with free private repositories is Bit Bucket.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Bitbucket which has most of the project management features, all of the cloud-based DCVS features and it has free private repositories so you can keep it on the DL.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can publish it in an early development - But mark it as pre-alpha, later set alpha, beta...

Comment: There's really no point to keeping track of that until you're actually planning to do a release (and even then, only if you're big enough that anyone would care).

Answer (score 1):

No one is just going to stumble on your project. And if they did they aren't going to go blabbing all over the internet about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it depends upon whether you think the code is incomplete or just plain bad.  If bad, you may want to consider whether you are now or might soon be looking for a new position; and whether or not the code is discoverable if a potential employer is researching you.

OTOH, even bad code might be considered a bonus, particulaly if it is commented as such.

My advice: decide with care.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can push whatever you want, but still it is better when you push a more pre beta solution to GitHub.

You can easily use [DropBox](http://db.tt/4nDhgNXz) for storing you GitHub projects and the good part is that you'll have access to them on any computer.

Comment: I strongly recommend against this.  From personal experience of doing so I found that I was getting a big mess of altered and reverted files due to both systems trying to get them in synch.  My approach is Dropbox for most stuff, 50GB plan and github for all code / version contolled files and ne'er the twain meetin' up.

Comment: I agree. Dropbox + git (especially the `.git` directory) do not mix.